# acces denied [15] Python VkApi

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

я делаю бота который будет отвечать на сообщения в группе но что то не получается в создании ботов я новичек пожалуйста подскажите что не так

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll,VkBotEventType
token = open('token.txt','r').read()
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = token)
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session,*айди группы*)
def message_send(id,text):
  vk_session.method('messages.send',{'chat_id':id, 'message':text, 'random_id':0})
for event in longpoll.listen():
  if event.type==VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
    if event.from_chat:
      msg = event.object.message['text'].lower()
      id = event.chat_id
      if msg=='/роли' or msg=='\роли':
        message_send(id,'пока нету ролей емое')
```

под словом *айди группы* подразумивается айди группы а в переменной token находится токен бота
токен проверял он правильный айди группы вроде бы тоже

> vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [15] Access denied

программа спотыкается на строчке

> longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session,*айди группы*)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключается в том, что для вашего токена требуются права доступа: messages. Так как метод messages.send можно вызвать с ключом доступа пользователя.